# How many times is this function executed in c++

Tags: c++

Here is a piece of c++ code, trying to understand and find out how many times the function is called.

```
#include <iostream>

int func(int j){
    if (j <= 0) return -1; 
    if (j == 1) return 1;  
    return func(j/2) + func(j-4); 
}

int main(){
    func(4);
}
```

Comment: Just put a `cout` statement in the function, and you'll see it.

Comment: https://ideone.com/FbRMsK

Comment: Try it with 40 instead of 4. Much more interesting.

Answer (score 0):

`func(4)` will be evaluated as  `func(2)+func(0)`. 
`func(2)` will in turn be evaluated as `func(1)+func(-2)`.
In total, you will call `func(4)`, `func(2)`, `func(1)`, `func(-2)`, `func(0)` (*5* times).
The resulting expression will be `func(1)+func(-2)+func(0)`, which is `1+(-1)+(-1)` or just `-1`.

An easy way to check that would be adding `std::cout << “something\n”;` in the first line of function definition.